# How to sit between seller and buyers as a payment gateway

Tags: php, payment, gateway

i need a solution so process is that i am creating a website that will have a payment processing. so payments have three parties let me explain below.

1. Fund Sender (buyer)
2. Primary Receiver (site owner)
3. Fund receiver (seller)

i want if sender (buyer) send 10 usd then site owner receive and system show balance of 8 usd in balance of receiver (seller) once receiver (seller) get balance greater or equal to 50 usd then receiver (seller) can release his fund to there verified payment system.

Now i want you to real story i need this system in php, so i also need a answer the following questions.

1. Which payment gateway i need to adopt ?
2. I don't have paypal can i do without paypal?
3. is there any ready made code in github?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of payment solutions out there. Please use google, the most of them have APIs but none are for free... (Paypal kinda is but you dont have)

You are acting like a bank in your plans, next to google i recommend a lawyer....